# Fill between relations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I am trying to make this graph.
[image]
Reading a bit I got information about shading the inner part between two functions, but in my case neither is a function. I tried to do the following, but no success.

*CODE:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=0:3,axis lines=middle,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,clip=false,
 xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
  \addplot[color=red,thick,name path=A] {sqrt(x)} node[right] {$y =\sqrt{x}$};
  \addplot[color=red,thick,name path=A] {-sqrt(x)} node[right] {$y =-\sqrt{x}$};
  \addplot[color=blue,thick,name path=B] {sqrt(9-x^2)}  node[right] {$y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$};    
  \addplot[cyan] fill between [of=B and A];
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to understand: You want to change color or transparancy of the intersection between the parabola and the circle? You do NOT want to change the two inequalities (which we call 'relation' in my country, too) ?

Comment: Forgive my bad English, I couldn't understand your question but the relations that I refer to are subsets of plane `R^2`. I want to graph exactly what is in the image, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}  
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=red, fill=red!10, dashed, semithick] 
    (0,0) circle[radius=3cm]; 
\node at (135:2) {$x^2 + y^2 < 9$};
\draw[smooth, blue,thick, name path=A]
    plot[samples at={0,0.025,...,0.5,1,...,4}] (\x,{ sqrt(\x)})  node[below=1em] {$x - y^2\geq 0$};
\draw[smooth, blue,thick, name path=B]
    plot[samples at={0,0.025,...,0.5,1,...,4}] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)});
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.3};
% axis
\draw[->]   (-4,0) -- ++ (9,0) node [below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]   (0,-4) -- ++ (0,8) node [below left] {$y$};
\foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}
{
\ifnum\i<180
    \node[above right] at (\i:3) {$3$};
\else
    \node[below left]  at (\i:3) {$-3$};
\fi
}
%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and effective answer!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with `parabola` section 14.9 The Parabola Operation of the pgfmanual documentation.

```
\draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=blue!10](-4,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(8,0);
```

Then with `\clip`, we color again the interior of the parabola

```
\begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (0,0) circle (3);
    \draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=red!20](-4,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(8,0);
\end{scope}
```

**code**

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684350/fill-between-relations
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[densely dashed,red, fill=red!10] (0,0) circle (3); 
\node at (135:4) {$x^2 + y^2 < 9$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% alternative
% \draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=cyan](-2,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(4,0);
\draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=blue!10](-4,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(8,0);
\begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (0,0) circle (3);
    % \draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=red!20](-2,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(4,0);
    \draw [rotate=-90,blue,thick,fill=red!20](-4,4) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend  +(0,-4) +(8,0);
\end{scope}
\node [right] at (4,2.5) {$x - y^2\geq 0$};

% % axis
\draw[->,>=latex]   (-4,0) -- ++ (9,0) node [below left] {$x$};
\draw[->,>=latex]   (0,-4) -- ++ (0,8) node [below left] {$y$};
%
\node[below left] at (-3,0) {$-3$};
\node[below right] at (3,0) {$3$};
\node[above left] at (0,3) {$3$};
\node[below left] at (0,-3) {$-3$};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]